# How to render components from json with inter-component messaging?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a JSON structure that I render.
I need to create messaging functionality between them.

*e.g*: once a user clicks MyButton (btn1), the value of MyInput (in1) must be present inside MyLabel (lbl1)

here is the codesandbox that rendered the json without data passing:
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-brahmagupta-sdn24m?file=/src/components/MyTabs.tsx

Here is the codesandbox that includes the data passing, but for some reason it re-renders infinitely:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-tdd-b9xbdw?file=/src/components/MyInput.tsx

why does it happen??

thanks